# Unable to compatible Organize imports between eclipse and intellij Idea for inner classes

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, formatting

As below, eclipse and intellij idea working differently for inner class DBInputSplit

Eclipse:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.DBInputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBWritable;
```

Intelliji Idea:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.DBInputSplit;
```

Here the order for DBInputSplit import differs. 
Any suggestion? Can we make intelliji orderding as same as Eclipse ordering.

For eclipse, we are using natural ordering (i.e. com, java, javax, org)

Comment: What is the point ?

Comment: @MickaëlB, so two team members can work in their IDE of choice and not unnecessarily pull imports either side on each of their commits.

Comment: It just changes the order of the imports. I don't see any side effect. Also I don't understand *"unnecessarily pull imports"*.

Comment: Have you tried Eclipse Code Formatter plugin?

Comment: @Meo Yes. We are using Eclipse Code Formatter and we imported eclipse java formatter and organised imports files to Intelliji

Comment: @MickaëlB , for source code repository perspective, this issue causes unnecessary commits.

Comment: @VijayKumarReddyChinnam If you are using Eclipse Code Formatter, then why are you asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup import ordering in IDEA: Settings-> Editor-> Code Style-> Java-> Look at bottom section "Import Layout".